# MYSQL query to return grouped result with certain requirements

Tags: mysql

I have this table

[image]

So it's a very simple table of messages: the message id (*message_id*) the sender id of the message (*sender_id*), when the message was sent (*time_stamp*), the body of the message (*message*), and whether the message was read or not (*is_read*).

I'd like an SQL to return one record per sender, with the sender_id, the time_stamp of the last message, the body of the last message and whether that sender has ANY unread messages. So the result should look like this:

sender_id, last_time_stamp, last_message, has_unread_messages

In other words, the query would GROUP By sender_id, so that there will be only one record per sender. This record would include the *sender_id*, the *time_stamp* of the last message, the body of the last message, and if that sender has any unread messages.

I've been wrecking my brain for the past 3 hours and cannot get this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please add sample input data and expected result into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT sender_id, time_stamp, message_body, is_read from messages where 
message_id IN ( SELECT MAX(message_id) from messages group by sender_id)
```

as it will give last message for each sender as @Alpesh mentioned without sample data it is not easy give exact query that you like.

Another query:

```
SELECT sender_id, time_stamp, message_body, has_unread_messages from messages 
INNER JOIN (SELECT sender_id, COUNT(1) AS has_unread_messages 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE is_read = 0 GROUP BY sender_id) AS senderUnread
    ON senderUnread.sender_id = messages.sender_id
WHERE message_id IN ( SELECT MAX(message_id) from messages group by sender_id)
```

It will give the latest message with total number of unread message based on sender_id.

Comment: Glad it helps :)